# How do I convert from unsigned char to long

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem to convert from unsigned char into long.

**The mission:** I have `25` in `(unsigned char) ptr->studentArr[i].subjectStatus` when `i = 0`, I go into the function `unsigned char fromDecToBinary(unsigned char tmpSubjectStatus)`, and I want in that function to get `unsigned long 11001` into variable `ret` and then `fprintf` it into `output.txt` file.

**Expectation:** to fprintf into the file `11001` when `i = 0`, problem: it prints `25` instead(if I use `fromDecToBinary` function, it prints `0`).

**Please,** just look at the 2 functions: `outPutStudents` and `fromDecToBinary`, other functions work properly, and those other functions just get the information and store the info. into structures which are then used to print the details into `output.txt`, most of them work, except the binary thingy.

**input.txt file:**

```
Nir 32251 99.80 11001
Ely 12347 77.89 01111
Moshe 45321 50.34 11111
Avi 31456 49.78 00011
```

***NOTE:** this is the output without using the function `fromDecToBinary`
**output.txt file:**

```
Student 1: Nir 32251 99.80 25  
Student 2: Ely 12347 77.89 15  
Student 3: Moshe 45321 50.34 31  
Student 4: Avi 31456 49.78 3
```

**Code:**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct Student{
    char* studentName; //Dyn. alloc. of stud. name
    long id; // ID Number
    float mark; // mark
    unsigned char subjectStatus;
}Student;

typedef struct University{
    Student* studentArr; // Dync. Alloc(Realloc) of students
    int numOfStudents; //num of students
}University;

void getStudents(University *ptr);
unsigned char stringToBinary(unsigned char tmpSubjectStatus[]);
void outPutStudents(University *ptr);
unsigned char fromDecToBinary(University *ptr);

void main()
{
    printf("Please enter details of student: (a)");
    University uni;
    getStudents(&uni); //Send address of structure University, because we want to change it not make a local copy of it
    outPutStudents(&uni);
    getch();
}
void getStudents(University *ptr)
{
    FILE *op;
    char tmpStudentName[20];
    long tmpId;
    float tmpMark;
    char tmpSubjectStatus[6];
    ptr->numOfStudents = 0;
    if ((op = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file.");
    }
    ptr->studentArr = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    if (ptr->studentArr == NULL){
        printf("Error: memory was not allocated.");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(op, "%s %ld %f %s", tmpStudentName, &tmpId, &tmpMark, tmpSubjectStatus) == 4)
    {
        ptr->numOfStudents++;
        ptr->studentArr = (Student*)realloc(ptr->studentArr, sizeof(Student) * ptr->numOfStudents); /*Additional code for Realloc fails - we didn't study!*/
        ptr->studentArr[ptr->numOfStudents - 1].studentName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* strlen(tmpStudentName));

        if (!(ptr->studentArr[ptr->numOfStudents - 1].studentName)) //if we failed to allocate memory for studentName
        {
            while (ptr->numOfStudents > 0)
            {
                free(ptr->studentArr[ptr->numOfStudents - 1].studentName); //free  student name
                ptr->numOfStudents--; // decrease numOfStudents by one
            }
            free(ptr->studentArr); //if all student names are free, we need to free the array
            printf("Student name was not allocated.");
            exit(1);
        }

        strcpy(ptr->studentArr[ptr->numOfStudents - 1].studentName, tmpStudentName);
        ptr->studentArr[ptr->numOfStudents - 1].id = tmpId;
        ptr->studentArr[ptr->numOfStudents - 1].mark = tmpMark;
        ptr->studentArr[ptr->numOfStudents - 1].subjectStatus = stringToBinary(tmpSubjectStatus); //atoi: from "11001"(string) to 11001(int),then casting to unsigned char
    }

    fclose(op);
}
void outPutStudents(University *ptr)
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned char tmpSubjectStatus;
    long val;
    if ((fp = fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open output file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; ptr->numOfStudents != i; i++){
        tmpSubjectStatus = ptr->studentArr[i].subjectStatus;
        val = fromDecToBinary(tmpSubjectStatus);
        fprintf(fp, "Student %d: %s %ld %.2f %ld  \n", i + 1, ptr->studentArr[i].studentName, ptr->studentArr[i].id, ptr->studentArr[i].mark, tmpSubjectStatus);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

unsigned char stringToBinary(char tmpSubjectStatus[])
{
    unsigned char tmpBinaryCh = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (tmpSubjectStatus[i] == '1') tmpBinaryCh += 1 << (4 - i);
    }

    return tmpBinaryCh;
}

unsigned char fromDecToBinary(unsigned char tmpSubjectStatus)
{
    int i;
    long ret;
    char arrBinary[6];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        arrBinary[4 - i] = tmpSubjectStatus % 2;
        tmpSubjectStatus /= 2;
    }
    arrBinary[5] = '/0';

    ret = strtol(arrBinary, NULL, 10);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You can't put 11001 into an `unsigned char` -- on almost all computer hardware the maximum possible value of `unsigned char` is 255.

Comment: @BillyONeal I see, how I convert unsigned char `25` into printing `long` 11001 then?

Comment: You can't. That's like saying "how do I put 5 gallons of milk into a 1 gallon milk jug"

Comment: @BillyONeal Well, I want to take unsigned char `25`, store it into an array as "11001" which I done by using the algorithm from decimal to binary, and now I want to print that array that contains "11001". It must be possible.

Comment: @BillyONeal I'm getting a new print into output.txt file now. (without using the function fromDecToBinary.

Comment: @BillyONeal - The proverb is [you can't get a quart into a pint pot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_can't_get_a_quart_into_a_pint_pot)

Comment: @BillyONeal Maybe I don't ask the exactly right question about the convert thingy, but it surely is possible to implement.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS printing a char array has nothing to do with `long`

Comment: @M.M Why not? I can use `strtol` to convert it from char array to long.

Comment: Or you could just print the char array

Comment: @M.M in `fromDecToBinary` function, `ret`'s value in `ret = strtol(arrBinary, NULL, 10)` is zero, it needs to be 11001 for `i=0` because 25 = 11001 in base 2.  do you know why it is like that?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about or why you want to involve `long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in the `fromDecToBinary` function:

- Replace the `'/0'` with `'\0'`.
- Store `'0' + tmpSubjectStatus % 2` in the array.
- Add proper error handling to the `strtol` call.
- Change the return type to `long`.

Comment: Nope, still `ret`'s value in `ret = strtol(arrBinary, NULL, 10)` is zero. this is why it doesn't matter what I return. do you know why it is like that?

Comment: I didn't know that `'0' + tmpSubjectStatus % 2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print some binary using numbers use this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_bin(uint64_t num, size_t bytes) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = bytes * 8; i > 0; i--) {
    (i % 8 == 0) ? printf("|") : 1;
    (num & 1)    ? printf("1") : printf("0");
    num >>= 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  int arg = atoi("25");
  print_bin(arg, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

It also prints a vertical bar every 8 bits to make the bytes easier to read but you can just remove that.

If you want to specify how many bytes you want use this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_bin(uint64_t num, size_t bytes) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = bytes * 8; i > 0; i--) {
    (i % 8 == 0) ? printf("|") : 1;
    (num & 1)    ? printf("1") : printf("0");
    num >>= 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  print_bin(16000, 3); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The strlen of the binary char has to be 5 as in the input. and I already implemented from dec to binary with my function `fromDecToBinary`

Comment: Let me change it to make it dyanmic. Two seconds

Comment: Harry, If you can change the function I wrote, it'd be highly appreciated, I don't really understand how I can implement your function in my code and make it work. :(

Comment: and your function isn't suitable for fprintf. it just prints into screen

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
unsigned char tmpSubjectStatus=25;
long quotient = tmpSubjectStatus;
long remainder;
long binary=0;
long multiplier=1;

while(quotient!=0){
     remainder=quotient % 2;
     binary=binary+(remainder*multiplier);
     multiplier=multiplier*10;
     quotient = quotient / 2;
}
     printf("%ld",binary);

return 0;
}
```

Try this.
In the function it will be like this

```
long fromDecToBinary(unsigned char tmpSubjectStatus)
{
long quotient = tmpSubjectStatus;
long remainder;
long binary=0;
long multiplier=1;

while(quotient!=0){
     remainder=quotient % 2;
     binary=binary+(remainder*multiplier);
     multiplier=multiplier*10;
     quotient = quotient / 2;
}

return binary;
}
```

In here return type is changed to long.